# Is there a way to get the uuid generated by Discord when i upload an image?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When we upload an image in Discord channel, the server will generate a uuid string for the image like the value of "upload_filename" in this screenshot[image]Is there a way to retrieve this uuid string with discord.py or any other way?

Comment: Is the UUID the `nonce` or *`uploaded_filename`* in the JSON?

Comment: It's the string in the uploaded_filename, actually I am not sure if that string is an uuid or not, the format just looks like uuid

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I guess `nonce` is a kind of UUID (but it's for the whole message, not only the file), and yes, the part before `/2.png` looks like one. How do you get it in discord.js/the Discord framework where you can get it? I'll try posting an answer, but I don't think you can do it with discord.py.

Comment: Also, how do you upload the image on Discord? And if you're talking about getting any kind of UUID generated by Discord for images uploaded by users/bots other than your bot, I don't think it's possible, as it might be confidential. So it might be inaccessible. If your bot uploads the image, please [edit] your question with the code used. See [mcve]. And I don't get any `uploaded_filename`. I only get `url` and `proxy_url`, which are Discord's CDN and media subdomain links which can be used to access the image.

Comment: @The Amateur Coder I tried to uploaded images by my own discord user account, just dragging images to the chat input field then open the devtools in chrome -> select network in the top tab -> select the message you just sent and select paload

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible, as you (your bot) most probably cannot access such information about files/images/messages uploaded by users, and even if you want to get that UUID via Python code, you'd have to upload the file via code, too, via a user account, which I guess is against Discord's ToS (not sure, but probably automating user-accounts is not allowed). If you want to get an attribute of a message your bot uploads, you can mostly get it using discord.py (without any additional libraries). If you want further help, please [edit] your question with related code ([mcve], [ask]).

Comment: The nonce is a snowflake, not a UUID.

What would you like to use the uploaded_filename for?